# Java Selenium webdriver access span element inside each div element from a autosuggest

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

am a newbie to selenium and am struggling with what looks to be a simple ask.
Using Java 8 with selenium webdriver and Chrome.

My requirement is to go to this website : https://start.duckduckgo.com/

In the search type : elephant
[image]

Now I need to retrieve all the autosuggested values using selenium.
From browser console I `think` this is the necessary HTML containing the auto suggestions :

```
<div class="search__autocomplete" style="display: block;">
<div class="acp-wrap js-acp-wrap">
    <div class="acp" data-index="0"><span class="t-normal">elephant toothpaste</span></div>
    <div class="acp" data-index="1"><span class="t-normal">elephant toothpaste</span> experiment</div>
    ...
</div>
<div class="acp-footer is-hidden js-acp-footer">
    <span class="acp-footer__instructions">Shortcuts to other sites to search off DuckDuckGo</span>
</div>
```

Here is the code I have tried with no luck :

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("https://start.duckduckgo.com/");
WebElement searchText = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
searchText.sendKeys("elephant");

List<WebElement> searchList = new ArrayList<WebElement>();


// have tried various options : all of the below selectors return no results

//searchList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'acp')]//span"));
//searchList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 
      'acp')]//span[contains(@class, 't-normal')]"));
//searchList = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".t-normal"));
//searchList = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("t-normal"));
//searchList = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".acp > span"));

// this atleast returns a collection of 10 but not sure of its content
searchList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'acp')]"));

if(null != searchList && searchList.size() > 0) {
        for(int i = 0;i<searchList.size();i++) {
            WebElement e = searchList.get(i);
            
            System.out.println("element details are " + e.toString());
            /** NoSuchElementException with below  tried Xpath and by css 
            WebElement spanElement = e.findElement(By.className("t-normal"));
            WebElement spanElement = e.findElement(By.className(".t-normal"));
            WebElement spanElement = e.findElement(By.cssSelector(".t-normal"));
            WebElement spanElement = e.findElement(By.cssSelector("t-normal"));
            **/
            
            WebElement spanElement = e.findElement(By.cssSelector("t-normal"));
    
            System.out.println(e.getText());
            
            
        }
    }else {
        System.out.println("<<<<< not able to locate >>>>>");
    }
```

If in browser I do a find using xpath I can locate these span elements :
`//div[contains(@class, 'acp-wrap js-acp-wrap')]//div[contains(@class, 'acp')]//span[contains(@class,'t-normal')]`

So really confused on how to extract text from within span ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
searchList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='acp']"))
for(int i = 0;i<searchList.size();i++) {
    System.out.println(searchList.get(i).getText());
```

Just get all 8 dropdown values and then print it's getText.

Comment: man you are a lifesaver , am kicking myself on not trying your suggestion ... :) , just curious why did any of the xpath and css selectors not work in identifying span element ?

Comment: t-normal needed to be .t-normal but not all 10 elements have that. You have a div tag that contains acp but it's acp-wrap.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a list of WebElements directly.

```
List<WebElement> searchList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='search__autocomplete'][contains(@style,'display: block')]/div/div"));
```

If you want to iterate through the list and capture the values in a new list then you can try the following -

```
List<String> listOfValues = new ArrayList<String>();

for(WebElement ele : searchList){
    String elementValue = ele.getText().toString().trim();
    listOfValues.add(elementValue);
}
```